# sizing images based on screen size / resolution

Tags: image, resize, size

I have some images I want to display on my page but based on the screen I show it on, the image shows on top of other elements on my page. And on mobile devices it is really bad! It is because the image is sized in pixels. How can I make the image size be relevant to the screen size/resolution? I use some js on this page to replace the main image on click. I was thinking of maybe setting the image as a background image in a div and sizing the div with a % value then making the div change based on the thumb image that's clicked using js. Would this solve my problem, or would I still have the image size problem?

My page is here - http://www.test25.net/gems/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=14&Itemid=126

Comment: found a work around for now :) Use css for setting "img {max-width: 100%; max-height:100%}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around for now :)

Use css for setting

```
img {
    max-width: 100%; 
    max-height:100%
}
```